# DataTable PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

why when i add a seconde DataTable in my page i lose the entire content of this page ? im using JSF PrimeFaces.

This is my first DataTable:

```
 <p:tab title="Projet"> 
 <!-- ======================== Contenu ======================== -->
 <br/>
   <h:form id="form">  

                                <p:dataTable var="car" value="xxxxx" selection="xxxx" selectionMode="single">  
                                        <f:facet name="header">  
                                            Listes des projets Gpsi  
                                        </f:facet>  

                                        <p:column>  
                                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                                <h:outputText value="Code" />  
                                            </f:facet>  
                                            <h:outputText value="xxxx" />  
                                        </p:column>  

                                        <p:column>  
                                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                                <h:outputText value="Intitulé" />  
                                            </f:facet>  
                                            <h:outputText value="xxxx" />  
                                        </p:column>  

                                        <p:column>  
                                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                                <h:outputText value="Dernière Etat" />  
                                            </f:facet>  
                                            <h:outputText value="xxxx" />  
                                        </p:column>  

                                        <p:column>  
                                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                                <h:outputText value="Domaine" />  
                                            </f:facet>  
                                            <h:outputText value="xxxx" />  
                                        </p:column>  

                                        <f:facet name="footer">  
                                            <p:commandButton value="Ouvrire" image="ui-icon ui-icon-search" update="form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()"/>  
                                        </f:facet>  
                                    </p:dataTable>  

                                    <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false" width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">  
                                        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  
                                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                                <p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/xxxx.jpg"/>  
                                            </f:facet>  

                                            <h:outputText value="Model:" />  
                                            <h:outputText value="xxxx" />  

                                            <h:outputText value="Year:" />  
                                            <h:outputText value="xxxx" />  

                                            <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />  
                                            <h:outputText value="xxxx" />  

                                            <h:outputText value="Color:" />  
                                            <h:outputText value="xxxx" />  
                                        </h:panelGrid>  
                                    </p:dialog>  
                                </h:form>
```

And this one in the seconde tab :

```
<p:tab title="Objets">                                                           
                        <h:form id="form">
                            <p:dataTable var="car" value="pppp"
                                         selection="mmmm" selectionMode="single">

                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Liste des Objets
                                </f:facet>

                                <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Model" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="Model" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Year" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="Year" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Manufacturer" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="Manufacturer" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Color" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="Color" />
                                </p:column>

                                <f:facet name="footer">
                                    <p:commandButton value="View" image="ui-icon ui-icon-search"
                                            update="form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()"/>
                                </f:facet>

                            </p:dataTable>

                            <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"
                                      width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">

                                <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <p:graphicImage value="sss"/>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <h:outputText value="Model:" />
                                    <h:outputText value="xxx" />

                                    <h:outputText value="Year:" />
                                    <h:outputText value="xxx" />

                                    <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />
                                    <h:outputText value="xxx" />

                                    <h:outputText value="Color:" />
                                    <h:outputText value="xxx" />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:dialog>
                        </h:form>                                     
                        <!-- ======================== FIN Contenu ===================== -->
                    </p:tab>
```

Comment: Is this the "real" code or a simplified version? Did you enclose the tabs with a tabview? Furthermore your forms have the same id. Don't know if this works. You could try to add both tables without the tabview and see if it works.

Answer (score 6):

You should try to enclose your tabView with a single **h:form**, then place your dataTables inside your tabs:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:tabView id="myTabView">
        <p:tab id="firstTab">
            <p:dataTable ....>
                ....
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="secondTab">
            <p:dataTable ....>
                ....
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two forms with the same id="form" --> error. Rename one of the forms.